# how do you manage your HTTP request in terms of JavaScript prototype programming.

Tags: javascript

In terms of prototype programming i can manage http ajax request using callback. I am looking for a batter solution can you explain me how do you manage your HTTP request in terms of JavaScript  prototype programming.

```
    var filterObj=(function(){
            var siteUrl='http://localhost/testproject/project';
           
            function jsonObj(callback){
              $.getJSON(siteUrl+"/posts?type[]=cfg",callback)
            }
            function projectObject(callback){
                jsonObj(function(result){
                    callback(result);
                })
            }
        
            return {    
                getProjectInfo:function(callback){
                    projectObject(function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        callback(data);
                    });
                 },
                getProjectCategoryInfo:function(){

                },
                getProjectLocation:function(){

                }
            }    

        })();

   filterObj.getProjectInfo(function(data){
        console.log(data);
   });
```

Comment: actually im looking for a batter solution how people manage their http request in terms of JavaScript prototype programming. I can manage the whole thing in my way but i feel there should be batter solutions.

Comment: what do you mean by "JavaScript prototype programming"? the prototype.js library? Or function inheritence?

Comment: I mean JavaScript prototype programming

Comment: And my answer is exactly using js prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is better to embrace Javascript's functional programming nature rather than emulate OOP. However this example can be perfectly translated to a constructor function. In ECMA 5 you can write:

```
function Filter(siteUrl) {
    this.siteUrl = siteUrl;
}
Filter.prototype.jsonObj = function (callback) {
    $.getJSON(this.siteUrl + "/posts?type[]=cfg", callback)
};
Filter.prototype.projectObject = function (callback) {
    this.jsonObj(function (result) {
        callback(result);
    })
};

Filter.prototype.getProjectInfo = function (callback) {
    projectObject(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        callback(data);
    });
};
Filter.prototype.getProjectCategoryInfo = function () {
    //some code
};
Filter.prototype.getProjectLocation = function () {
    //some code
};


//Instanciate it
var filterObj = new Filter('http://localhost/testproject/project');

filterObj.getProjectInfo(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

In ECMA 6 or Typescript you have a much cleaner syntax with the class keyword. [You can write a class in Typescript playground and see the resulting ECMA 5 code in real time here.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground) Pick the *Walkthrough: classes*  from the drop down menu for example to see how the new syntax simplifies working with prototypes.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. This way is good but my problem is handling callback function in case of managing HTTP request and handling their response and other dependency.

Comment: You mean the `error()` and `done()` functions? Can you clarify what you mean by handling dependencies'?

Comment: For example, you need to add project category and project price and some other information in different fields when http request is done you have to sort the value and update the content using 3 separate functions.In my experience,  one can easily mange it using callback. but think about the scenario after a lot of callbacks creating complexity over the period for adding new functionality.

In that situation what will be your suggestion?

Comment: I see what you mean. This is called "callback-hell" and is a typical issue in asynchronous programming. Promises make the code much more readable and managable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise In ECMA 7 we'll have aync/await which makes it even more easy to write such code. JQuery `done()` function behaves like a promise as well.

Comment: Thanks AlexStack for your reply.